# Custom characters of tinymce editor are saved as question mark

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, tinymce

I have integrated tinymce editor of wordpress to my custom plugin. I save the data entered in to Database via ajax like this:

```
encodeURIComponent('<?php echo mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['title'])); ?>');
```

But in frontend as well as in DataBase **Custom Characters like diamond** etc are **stored and displayed as question mark.**

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode the string you store in UTF-8 or whatever the site is using as encoding.

If you don’t store valid UTF-8 you get the famous diamonds. In websites, these are not girls best friends, they just break your output. :)

See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56416/73) for some code to encode text as UTF-8 in PHP.

Comment: Diamonds may be forever, but so are encoding conflicts ;)