# wp_insert_post and title not utf8 inserts with empty title?

Tags: wp-insert-post, encoding

I'm using `wp_insert_post` I loop over a text file one row at a time and for each row, I create a post. The text is set as the `post_title', for the text that is not utf8 the post inserts but with an empty title.

Why does that happen, if I'm able to create a post in the backend admin using non-utf8 chars it looks like WordPress converts the encoding in the backend.

How can I bypass this with `wp_insert_post` and have it insert the post title with non-utf8 chars?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to insert invalid data into your database? This will break everything. And no, you cannot enter non-UTF-8 characters in the back end.

Comment: @Toscho I just tested entering `ā` into a custom field from the backend and it saved. WordPress is correcting the slug which is great, and keeps the title and permalink in the backend but why not when I use `wp_insert_post` isn't it running the same actions as from the backend to create the posts?

Comment: `ā` is a valid UTF-8 character, depending on the encoding. You _have_ to make sure the correct encoding is used, or MySQL must reject the input. See [this function](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56416/73) for one way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the text encoding you are using is not set to UTF8, try to use iconv() and set.

> iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8', $post_info['post_content']);

Answer (score 0):

This is where the [WordPress data sanitization functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/) come in handy, specifically `sanitize_text_field()`. Try using that function on your text before/while inserting it. This should also be safe for the lines that are currently working.

```
wp_insert_post(array(
   'post_title' => sanitize_text_field( $text_from_row )
));
```